# Is there any equivalent of SQL IN (...) query in Laravel for multiple if condition?

Tags: laravel, if-statement

Using laravel, I'm making an `if` with many `||` conditions, and I have to write the same syntaxes over and over.

My code example:

```
if (type == 1 ||  type == 2 || type == 3 || type == 4){
    // my code
}
```

Is there any shorthand syntax for this? Maybe like an `IN` operator in SQL.

```
IF type IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use PHPs in array function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

```php
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

if (in_array($type, $arr) {

}
```

If you have multiple groups of values to compare to, use switch()

```
switch($type) {
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        echo 'group 1';
        break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
        echo 'group 2';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'no group found';
        break;
}
```